# Automating services with Linux OS starting up and shutting down

Tags: linux, shell, server

I have  a script to start and stop my services. My server is based on Linux. How do I automate the process such that when OS is shutdown the stop script runs and when it is starting up, the start script runs?

Comment: what you have done so far

Comment: This question heavily depends on the init system your distribution uses: sysv-init or systemd, upstart?

Comment: @jmajnert: Actually all should support LSB.

Comment: @Jan Hudec - some are easier to use than others

Comment: @jmajnert: Yes, they are. And LSB is not the simplest one, by far. But it will work on any system.

Answer (score 1):

You should install init script for your program. The standard way is to follow [Linux Standards Base section 20 subsections 2-8](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/tocsysinit.html)

The idea is to create a script that will start your application when called with argument `start`, stop it when called with argument `stop`, restart it when called with argument `restart` and make it reload configuration when called with argument `reload`. This script should be installed in `/etc/init.d` and linked in various `/etc/rd.*` directories. The standard describes a comment to put at the beginning of the script and a uitlity to handle the installation.

Please, refer to the documentation; it is to complicated to explain everything in sufficient detail here.

Now that way should be supported by all Linux distribution. But Linux community is currently searching for better init system and there are two new, improved, systems being used:

- [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) is what most of the world seems to be going to
- [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) is a solution Ubuntu created and sticks to so far

They provide some better options like ability to restart your application when it fails, but your script will then be specific to the chosen system.

Comment: Hi Jan, Actually i want that my start script to be executed whenever the system is booted up and stop script to be executed when the OS is shutdown. But if i place my script for these in /etc/init.d then both will be executed whenever system is started or stopped. Is there a way around for this?

Comment: @user227668: By placing the script in `/etc/init.d` the script won't be run yet. You need to add the comments and run the `/usr/lib/lsb/install_initd` to set up the links. Read the documentation, it explains how to set the runlevels.